# Ant Colony Optimization Path

Tags: algorithm, optimization, html5-canvas, path-finding

Good Day Everyone! I am new to this site so I'm sorry if I've made any mistake in the format of my post!

I am doing an undergrad thesis project on **Ant Colony Optimization** and I was just wondering if anyone knows how to **set up the "map" or "path"** for where the ants would be searching. I'm trying to implement it on **html** and I've read that the canvas tag could be a possible solution.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Both html5 canvas and SVG will draw maps and will draw paths upon those maps. Both will animate travel along those paths.

Comment: Have you considered using Java? It has strong Graphs libraries and may be helpful.